# python multi-dimensional array multiplication behavior

Tags: python, list

I wrote this code to do an mean filtering to a given image.
In it, I first initialize a 2-d array. But when I try to assign a value to a specific cell it actually assigned the value to the whole column. See below:

```
def boxBlur(image):    
    height = len(image)
    width = len(image[0])
    result = [[0]*(width-2)]*(height-2)
    for i in range(height-2):
        for j in range(width-2):                         
            mysum = image[i][j] + image[i][j+1] + image[i][j+2] + image[i+1][j] + image[i+1][j+1] + image[i+1][j+2] + image[i+2][j] + image[i+2][j+1] + image[i+2][j+2]            
            result[i][j] = mysum / 9
            print result        

boxBlur([[7,4,0,1], 
 [5,6,2,2], 
 [6,10,7,8], 
 [1,4,2,0]])
```

The output is like:

```
[[5, 0], [5, 0]]
[[5, 4], [5, 4]]
[[4, 4], [4, 4]]
[[4, 4], [4, 4]]
```

Can anyone explain exactly what's behind this behavior?

Comment: `result = [[0]*(width-2)]*(height-2)` be aware that all inner lists are one and the same.

Comment: Why aren't they fixed once I initialize 'result'?

Comment: These are *lists* not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The array 'multiplication' is copying a reference to the thing you are multiplying i.e. each element of the generated array points to the same actual instance. Hence, modifying one modifies all the elements.

Comment: Thanks! 'Copying a reference' is on spot.